# Writing compressed gzipstream to a file

Tags: c#, .net, gzipstream

I have a `gzipstream` that is compressed and I want to write it to a file. Now the problem is that the Read is not supported on the `gzipstream` that is compressed. Below is my code where the gzipstream reads the `stream` from a `memorystream` and then I want to write it to a `filestream`.

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (FileStream file = new FileStream(@"c:\newest.xml.gz", 
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        using (GZipStream gzs = new GZipStream(file, CompressionLevel.Fastest))
        {
            stream.CopyTo(gzs);
        }
    }  
}
```

Any idea how I can create a `filestream` from a compressed `gzipstream`?

EDIT:

That was my bad, sorry to have waste your time. For future reference the code above should work, the problem was somewhere else.

Comment: Why do you want to compress `stream` and then decompress it?

Comment: Essentially I need to compress the file and store it as .gz in my file system...

Comment: Then why are you using `gzs` with `CompressionMode.Decompress`?

Comment: My bad, that was the wrong chunk of code...

Comment: I was about to post an answer about how to write to a compressed file but after you have changed you question you are doing it correctly and as far as I can see you should no longer encounter the error you describe.

Comment: Yes Martin, I realised what I was doing wrong there. But now although my stream is not empty, I get an empty compressed file? Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reading and writing the same memory stream. I don't think that's possible; you should use two different streams: one from which you read, and another into which you write:

```
using (gzipStream = new GZipStream(writeStream,CompressionLevel.Fastest))
{
    readStream.CopyTo(gzipStream);
}
```